# Validate if a element exists on FormGroup - Typescript

Tags: typescript, formgroups

I have this FormGroup (I will call it form) where I will set a bunch of values from a object:

My atual code:

```
if(form.get('value1') && myObj.val1){
   form.get('value1).patchValue(myObj.val1);
}
if(form.get('value2') && myObj.val2){
   form.get('value2).patchValue(myObj.val2);
}
if(form.get('value3') && myObj.val3){
   form.get('value3).patchValue(myObj.val3);
}
```

There is not a better way to achieve this without using so many if?

Comment: You are not the first scratching your head about it. There are actually some work going in this direction: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Answer (score 1):

You could define a mapping and iterate over it, something like this:

```
const map: [string, string][] = [
    ['value1', 'val1'],
    ['value2', 'val2'],
    ['value3', 'val3'],
]

for (const [formName, propertyName] of map)
{
    if(form.get(formName) && myObj[propertyName])
        form.get(formName).patchValue(myObj[propertyName]);
}
```